# Bitwise Operator in C ~=

Tags: java, c, io, bitwise-operators

I am working on interpreting C code and direct translation to Java for my Java class. I was doing fine until I got to the line:

```
fread(&pLength, 1, 1, stream);
if( pLength ~= 170) break;
```

`pLength` is a `unsigned char`, and `stream` is `File *stream = 0`. All help will be appreciated!

P.S. `stream` is any method of serial i/o.

Edit:
A lot of people have mentioned that its not possible to directly translate this code, as java does not posses the access to pointers. That is my fault for poor wording. However, I do need to figure out what ~= means.

Comment: This is not possible to directly translate to Java since you don't have access to pointers in the language. You will need to come up with a way to accomplish it without a direct translation.

Comment: What is `~=` even supposed to do? It does not exist in standard C.

Comment: @sreisman by direct translation, I meant a translation in which the code operates in a similar fashion, i.e. I don't change the algorithm or the names. I just need to find out what ~= means.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Thats what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @oakTree well, it doesn't exist in standard C. There's a unary `~` that's basically a bitwise not. `~x` would 'flip' all the bits of x, turning '1' bits into '0' bits an vice versa. `a ~= b` (combined assignment) or `a ~ b` (binary operator) don't exist.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Thank you. I am not all that familiar with the bitwise operators for C, and I was not aware that it does not exist in standard C. I talked to the professor, and he says it is not a typo. I cannot find a library in which that exists, however.

Comment: @oakTree - *I talked to the professor, and he says it is not a typo.*  What's the intended platform and compiler?  Punctuators are enumerated in **6.4.6 Puctuators** of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  `~=` isn't one of them.  Assignment operators are in **6.5.16 Assignment Operators**.  Again, `~=` isn't one of them.  Splitting `~=` into `~` then `=` makes no sense, either.  So it would help to provide more context regarding the actual use of such code.

Comment: @oakTree: it *has* to be a typo; there is no such operator in standard C, and all other compound assignment operators use a binary operator (`+=`, `-=`, `*=`, etc.), but `~` is strictly a unary operator.  Your professor must have meant `==` or `!=` in that place.  What platform is that code meant to run on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because `if( pLength ~= 170) ...` in not valid C syntax and so has not definable meaning C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `~=` is the C representation of "not equal to", you would use `!=` instead. However, `~=` is not a valid operator in C; and just like sreisman said, the JVM does not have access to memory pointers, so the code doesn't have any direct translation.

Comment: But a pointer isn't necessary - `pLength` is an `unsigned char` - the `&` operator just converts it to an address because C is pass-by-value - the equivalent of defining `unsigned char pLength[1]; fread(pLength, ...);` (note the *lack* of `&` there), then getting the byte read with `pLength[ 0 ]`.  With Java you'd get a one-byte byte array and call something like `byte array[] = new byte[1];anInputStream.read( array );`

Comment: And note that `~=` is not a valid operator in C.